# js-translation.json sample

Tags: magento2, js-translation

I am having a translation issue where magento generates empty js-translation.json files only. This issue has been reported a number of times:

Github:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/8508
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/9073
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4067

Magento.stackexchange / stackoverflow:

[Magento 2 - Translations : how does js-translation.json get populated? Mine is empty!](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/158359/magento-2-translations-how-does-js-translation-json-get-populated-mine-is-e/158365?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35876380/magento-2-translating-strings-in-js-ko

(Many more example can be found on google for these or similar.)

The only general solution seems to be to generate the file yourself. Now, It looks like the format described here should work: http://i18njs.com/ , but magento can handle a couple more things, like making translations dependent on modules and such.

Could someone give me a sample of a working js-translation.json file? Just a translatable string or 2 should probably be enough for me to create my own file.

Answer (score 0):

`js-translation.json` file contains only array, so technically you can just add `[]`.

If you have problem with autogeneration, use simple command: `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --theme=Vendor/Theme en_US -f` with your theme: `Vendor/Theme` and language code: `en_US`.

Comment: Autotheme generation, even with that command, didn't work. We already tried that. Also, I know the empty array - that's all we have. What I needed is a sample of how to map values.

Comment: [edit timed out] Currently, we have just changed the template that generated the javascript, which works well enough. (the javascript in question was in a phtml template, so I shifted the translation to PHP.)(file in question was vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/base/templates/product/price/tier_price.phtml)

Comment: Map is pretty simple - just a key:value:
`["Please enter at least {0} characters":"Podaj co najmniej {0} znaków"]`

Comment: That's not even valid JSON. Or are you talking about `{"Please enter at least {0} characters":"Podaj co najmniej {0} znaków"}`, with the curly braces? If so, update the answer with that and I'll accept it.

Comment: Sure, sorry for the mistake.