# Magento2: How to translate text from html file

Tags: magento2, translate

We have file: web/template/checkout/order-comment-block.html

in this file I see code:

```
                        <span class="chars-label">
                        <!-- ko i18n: 'remaining characters'--><!-- /ko -->
                        </span>
```

I created new folder `i18n` and here I add translate text:

```
"Leave A Comment","Wiadomość do zamówienia"
"Enter your comment...","Zostaw swój komentarz..."
```

After cache clean still text are not translated. Any solution how to translate this text?

Comment: your multistore website???

Comment: Yes, mulitwebsite. One website assigned to one store view.

Comment: check this --- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/229607/magento-2-how-to-translate-text-in-knockout-html-file

Comment: @Mohit, once again thank you for your support ;) I have one more question for you. Can you please check our question here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/311299/magento2-custom-shipping-method-with-dropdown

Comment: Like example here: https://zanetabaran.com/how-to-in-magento-2-how-to-add-additional-dropdown-with-options-based-on-selected-shipping-methods-in-the-checkout/ But how to set example only for this one specific shipping?

Comment: above links help solve or not ???

Comment: About translate - yes solved our issue.

Comment: above link add answer??? To other community to see easy and help...

Comment: Mohit, I found other quick solution for this but still I have any issue. Can you please check this question: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/311305/magento2-issue-with-additional-dropdown-option-in-checkout and try debug for us? Then I approved answear for you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You check two link most useful i think :-

[Magento 2- How to translate text in Knockout .html file](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/229607/magento-2-how-to-translate-text-in-knockout-html-file)

[Magento 2 - Translations : how does js-translation.json get populated? Mine is empty!](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/158359/magento-2-translations-how-does-js-translation-json-get-populated-mine-is-e?rq=1)

And this links use for multi store website text translate.

Hope help you

Thanks ...