# Magento2: Issue with additional dropdown option in checkout

Tags: magento2

I used module delivery date from: 
https://github.com/sohelrana09/magento2-module-delivery-date/tree/master/SR/DeliveryDate

I want to this module add custom dropdown option, should be like this:
[image]

Here I edit file:
Modify following class app/code/SR/DeliveryDate/Model/DeliveryDateConfigProvider.php

```
namespace SR\DeliveryDate\Model;

use Magento\Checkout\Model\ConfigProviderInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;

class DeliveryDateConfigProvider implements ConfigProviderInterface
{
    const XPATH_FORMAT = 'sr_deliverydate/general/format';
    const XPATH_DISABLED = 'sr_deliverydate/general/disabled';
    const XPATH_HOURMIN = 'sr_deliverydate/general/hourMin';
    const XPATH_HOURMAX = 'sr_deliverydate/general/hourMax';

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    protected $scopeConfig;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    ) {
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getConfig()
    {
        $store = $this->getStoreId();
        $disabled = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XPATH_DISABLED, ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE, $store);
        $hourMin = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XPATH_HOURMIN, ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE, $store);
        $hourMax = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XPATH_HOURMAX, ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE, $store);
        $format = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XPATH_FORMAT, ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE, $store);

        $noday = 0;
        if($disabled == -1) {
            $noday = 1;
        }

        $config = [
            'shipping' => [
                'delivery_date' => [
                    'format' => $format,
                    'disabled' => $disabled,
                    'noday' => $noday,
                    'hourMin' => $hourMin,
                    'hourMax' => $hourMax,
                    'customOptionValue' => $this->getCustomOptionValue()
                ]
            ]
        ];

        return $config;
    }

    public function getStoreId()
    {
        return $this->storeManager->getStore()->getStoreId();
    }

    public function getCustomOptionValue()
    {
        return [
            'option1' => 'Option 1',
            'option2' => 'Option 2',
            'option3' => 'Option 3'
        ];
    }
}
```

app/code/SR/DeliveryDate/view/frontend/web/js/view/delivery-date-block.js

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'ko',
    'uiComponent'
], function ($, ko, Component) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'SR_DeliveryDate/delivery-date-block',
            customOptionValue: ''
        },
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();
            var disabled = window.checkoutConfig.shipping.delivery_date.disabled;
            var noday = window.checkoutConfig.shipping.delivery_date.noday;
            var hourMin = parseInt(window.checkoutConfig.shipping.delivery_date.hourMin);
            var hourMax = parseInt(window.checkoutConfig.shipping.delivery_date.hourMax);
            var format = window.checkoutConfig.shipping.delivery_date.format;
            if(!format) {
                format = 'yy-mm-dd';
            }
            var disabledDay = disabled.split(",").map(function(item) {
                return parseInt(item, 10);
            });

            ko.bindingHandlers.datetimepicker = {
                init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
                    var $el = $(element);
                    //initialize datetimepicker
                    if(noday) {
                        var options = {
                            minDate: 0,
                            dateFormat:format,
                            hourMin: hourMin,
                            hourMax: hourMax
                        };
                    } else {
                        var options = {
                            minDate: 0,
                            dateFormat:format,
                            hourMin: hourMin,
                            hourMax: hourMax,
                            beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                                var day = date.getDay();
                                if(disabledDay.indexOf(day) > -1) {
                                    return [false];
                                } else {
                                    return [true];
                                }
                            }
                        };
                    }

                    $el.datetimepicker(options);

                    var writable = valueAccessor();
                    if (!ko.isObservable(writable)) {
                        var propWriters = allBindingsAccessor()._ko_property_writers;
                        if (propWriters && propWriters.datetimepicker) {
                            writable = propWriters.datetimepicker;
                        } else {
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    writable($(element).datetimepicker("getDate"));
                },
                update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
                    var widget = $(element).data("DateTimePicker");
                    //when the view model is updated, update the widget
                    if (widget) {
                        var date = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
                        widget.date(date);
                    }
                }
            };

            return this;
        },
        initObservable: function () {

            this._super()
                .observe([
                    'customOptionValue'
                ]);
            return this;
        },
        getCustomOption: function() {
            return _.map(window.checkoutConfig.shipping.delivery_date.customOptionValue, function(value, key) {
                return {
                    'value': key,
                    'label': value
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

app/code/SR/DeliveryDate/view/frontend/web/template/fields/delivery-date.html

```
   <input class="input-text" type="text" data-bind="
    event: {change: userChanges},
    hasFocus: focused,
    value: value,
    datetimepicker: true,
    attr: {
        name: inputName,
        placeholder: placeholder,
        'aria-describedby': noticeId,
        disabled: disabled
    }" readonly="true"/>

    <select name="custom_option"
            class="select"
            data-bind="
                                  options: getCustomOption(),
                                  optionsValue: 'value',
                                  optionsText: 'label',
                                  optionsCaption: $t('Option'),
                                  value: customOptionValue">
    </select>
```

and here is result:
[image]

Something went wrong. Because when I select this dropdown then no option available. Can anyone check this code?

**update2:**

Now this option working but I see is any issue with confirmation of the order. In 2/2 step checkout during select payment method and confirm order we received issue.
[image]

log:

```
[2020-04-25 20:55:45] main.CRITICAL: Invalid Delevery Date {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Invalid Delevery Date at /home/usr/domains/domain.com/public_html/app/code/SR/DeliveryDate/Observer/SalesModelServiceQuoteSubmitBefore.php:46)"} []
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your all code correct.But you show output put the wrong file.So You html code put `delivery-date-block.html` file .

```
<!-- ko foreach: getRegion('delivery-date-block') -->
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
<!--/ko-->
<select name="custom_option"
            class="select"
            data-bind="
                                  options: getCustomOption(),
                                  optionsValue: 'value',
                                  optionsText: 'label',
                                  optionsCaption: $t('Option'),
                                  value: customOptionValue">
    </select>
```

After run the : ---

```
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento c:f
```

And check output :-

[image]

Hope help you

Thanks...

Comment: Now this option working but I see is any issue with confirmation of the order. In 2/2 step checkout during select payment method and confirm order we received issue. Can you plaese check our update?

Comment: you means showing issues ??? yes, what issues showing???

Comment: I update my question with error log and screen.

Comment: my place order button working fine and place the order

Comment: i think you run all command with permission

Comment: Yes i have find the problem. what problem you are not add the date . so showing this error.you add the data in data filed after try ...

Comment: Let me check again

Comment: okay check update me...

Comment: I accept your answer and send you one question via Skype. If this case require question here you can let me know. Thanks